# Minimizing a damping constant in order to minimize the amplitude of oscillations

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, eigenvalue, differential-equations

> How can I determine the damping coefficient that minimizes the amplitude of vibrations?
>   This is an extension of [Coupled ODEs that model a quad rotor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/147525/coupled-odes-that-model-a-quad-rotor/151308#151308)
>   \begin{align}                                                                   
>   m_{eq}\ddot{y}_1                                                              
>   &= k_{eq}\Bigl[y_1 + \frac{m_{eq}}{m_b}\sum_jy_j\Bigr] +                      
>      c\Bigl[\dot{y}_1 + \frac{m_{eq}}{m_b}\sum_j\dot{y}_j\Bigr] - m_{eq}gy_1 +  
>      F_1(t)\\                                                                   
>   m_{eq}\ddot{y}_2                                                              
>   &= k_{eq}\Bigl[y_2 + \frac{m_{eq}}{m_b}\sum_jy_j\Bigr] +                      
>      c\Bigl[\dot{y}_2 + \frac{m_{eq}}{m_b}\sum_j\dot{y}_j\Bigr] - m_{eq}gy_2 +  
>      F_2(t)\\                                                                   
>   m_{eq}\ddot{y}_3                                                              
>   &= k_{eq}\Bigl[y_3 + \frac{m_{eq}}{m_b}\sum_jy_j\Bigr] +                      
>      c\Bigl[\dot{y}_3 + \frac{m_{eq}}{m_b}\sum_j\dot{y}_j\Bigr] - m_{eq}gy_3 +  
>      F_3(t)\\                                                                   
>   m_{eq}\ddot{y}_4          
> &= k_{eq}\Bigl[y_4 + \frac{m_{eq}}{m_b}\sum_jy_j\Bigr] +                      
>      c\Bigl[\dot{y}_4 + \frac{m_{eq}}{m_b}\sum_j\dot{y}_j\Bigr] - m_{eq}gy_4 +  
>      F_4(t)                                                                     
> \end{align}
>   where $F_i(t) = F_i\cos(\omega t + \phi)$

---

I tried converting to the state space equation but this doesn't make the system any easier to deal with:

By letting $q_1 = y_1$, $q_2 = \dot{y}_1$, $q_3 = y_2$, $q_4 = \dot{y}_2$, $q_5 = y_3$, $q_6 = \dot{y}_3$, $q_7 = y_4$, and $q_8 = \dot{y}_4$, we obtain the following state equations.
\begin{align}                                                                   
  \dot{\mathbf{q}}                                                              
  &=                                                                            
    \begin{bmatrix}                                                             
      0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\                                           
      a & b & C & d & C & d & C & d\\                                           
      0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\                                           
      C & d & a & b & C & d & C & d\\                                           
      0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\                                           
      C & d & C & d & a & b & C & d\\                                           
      0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\                                           
      C & d & C & d & C & d & a & b                                             
    \end{bmatrix}\mathbf{q} +              
  \frac{1}{m_{eq}}                              
                                  \begin{bmatrix}                               
                                    F_1(t)\\                                    
                                    F_2(t)\\                                    
                                    F_3(t)\\                                    
                                    F_4(t)                                      
                                  \end{bmatrix}^{\intercal}                     
  \begin{bmatrix}                                                               
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\                                             
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\                                             
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\                                             
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1                                               
  \end{bmatrix}\\                                                
  \mathbf{y} &=                                       
 \begin{bmatrix}                                                  
                 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\                                
                 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\                                
                 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\                                
                 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0                                  
               \end{bmatrix}\mathbf{q}                               
\end{align}
where $a = \frac{k_{eq}}{m_{eq}} + \frac{k_{eq}}{m_b} - g$, $b = \frac{c}{m_{eq}} + \frac{c}{m_b}$, $C = \frac{k_{eq}}{m_b}$, and $d = \frac{c}{m_b}$.

If I take $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{(s\mathbb{I} - \mathbf{A})^{-1}\}$ with Mathematica, the solution is ridiculously long.

I have also tried setting up $[m]\ddot{y} + [c]\dot{y} + [k]y = [F]$ but I am not sure how to solve this equation either.

Answer (score 1):

You should use complex numbers. Assume the solution is of the form
$y_i(t)=\tilde Y_i\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\omega t}$ where $\tilde Y_i$ is complex. Write also $\tilde F_i=F_i\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\phi_i}$ such that $F_i(t)=\mathrm{Re}(\tilde F_i\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\omega t})$. The system of equations becomes "simply" (it's "only" of the fourth order)
$$ (\omega^2+b\mathrm i\omega+a)\tilde Y_i+(C+d\mathrm i\omega) \sum_j\tilde Y_j=-\tilde F_i.$$
Let us write $$\mathbb U=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1\end{pmatrix}.$$
$\mathbb U$ has characteristic polynomial equal to $\Delta=X^4-4X^3$ has $\Delta$ has only two roots : 0 and 4. The determinant of the system is the determinant of $A=(\omega^2+b\mathrm i\omega+a)\mathbb I+(C+d\mathrm i\omega)\mathbb U$, so is equal to
$$\delta=(C+d\mathrm i\omega)^4 \,\Delta\left(-\frac{\omega^2+b\mathrm i\omega+a}{C+d\mathrm i\omega}\right)=(C+d\mathrm i\omega)^4+4(\omega^2+b\mathrm i\omega+a)(C+d\mathrm i\omega)^3.$$
The solutions of the system are given by Cramér's rules: 
$\tilde Y_i=\mathrm{det}B_i/\delta,$ where $B_i$ is the matrix made of the original matrix $A$ in which one replace the $i^{\rm th}$ column by the right hand side $(\tilde F_i)_{i}^T$. The damping corresponds to the imaginary part of the solutions $\tilde Y_i$. 
From this point, you should be able to take and find the optimal damping coefficient.

**Note**. There seems to be some mistakes in your starting equations. The sign in front of $k_{\rm eq}$ is wrong and leads to exponential explosion of $y_i$. Moreover, the term $-mgy$ is dimensionally inconsistent.

Comment: I noticed that yesterday as well. It should read -k_{eq}( + ) and -c( + ). I forgot the negative when plugging in z.

Comment: How should the gravity term be written then?

Comment: If you have a, b, C, d defined as I did, your U should be $$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\1 & 1 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: With the U I supplied, $\Delta = (x - 3)(x + 1)^3$. Also, making the negative correction leads to $$(a + bi\omega - \omega^2)\mathbb{I} + (C + di\omega)\mathbb{U} = A$$